# why is this php json not working

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have created a simple PHP script. If you enter `"hello"` as POST parameter `name`, it should return error. Otherwise, it should return success. The return value should appear in DIV.

But it is not working? Why not?

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    if($name == 'hello'){
        echo json_encode(array('comment_error' => 'You cant say hello'));
    } else {

    }
    echo json_encode(array('comment_success' => 'awesome! It worked'));

}
```

Here is the javascript that parses response:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'comment/post.php',
     data: {name:name},
     dataType: 'json',
     success:function(data){
            if(data.comment_error){
                 alert(data.comment_error);
            } else {
                 $('div').append(data.comment_success);
            }
     }
});
```

Comment: The success code is outside the else statement?

Comment: Also you should set the correct json content type header in your php

Comment: also need  var json = $.parseJSON(data);

Comment: what you get error? Is your ajax call working?

Comment: This is not working because you're sending 2 json encoded strings on  `hello` case. You need to `exit` or `return` the script right after you send a json string.

Comment: im getting an error when i add this, var json = $.parseJSON(data);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move last line of php code into else condition and change the js code

```
data = JSON.parse(data); // add this in your call back
if(data.comment_error){
    alert(data.comment_error);
} else {
    $('div').append(data.comment_success);
}
```

Comment: im getting this when i add that .  Unexpected token o

Comment: so to debug it do console.log(data); return; before data = JSON.parse(data); line, and check the console if there is any error in php or whether your output is in right json format

Comment: yeah im getting "Object {comment_error: "You cant say hello"} "

Comment: remove data = JSON.parse(data); and try again

Answer (score 2):

you have to send Json header header('Content-Type: application/json');

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');   
if(isset($_POST)){

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    if($name == 'hello'){
        echo json_encode(array('comment_error' => 'You cant say hello'));
    } else {

    }
    echo json_encode(array('comment_success' => 'awesome! It worked'));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your `if else loop`

code should be like this

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');  

if(isset($_POST)){
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        if($name == 'hello'){
            echo json_encode(array('comment_error' => 'You cant say hello'));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('comment_success' => 'awesome! It worked'));
        }


    }
```

Comment: added, still wont work. Is this not a javascript problem

Comment: what you get error? Is your ajax call working?

Answer (score 0):

Put this 
echo json_encode(array('comment_success' => 'awesome! It worked'));
inside else like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');   
if(isset($_POST)){

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    if($name == 'hello'){
        echo json_encode(array('comment_error' => 'You cant say hello'));
    } else {
       echo json_encode(array('comment_success' => 'awesome! It worked'));
    }

}
```

Btw. if you are using free host to test your script like 000webhost, you should know that they put extra lines of code in the html. If so Ajax can not parse the json object.

This cannot be parsed:

```
<!-- Blabla 000webhost free hosting blabla -->
{"comment_success" : "awesome! It worked"} 
<!-- Blabla 000webhost free hosting blabla -->
```

P.S you don't need var `json = $.parseJSON(data);` because `dataType = 'json'` does it for you. I mean in success "data" is already a JSON object.